# Как сделать постоянное изменение цвета текста и фона в консоли на С?

Tags: c, windows, текст, цвета, консоль

Язык - С

(меню для игры) я сделал, что выводятся 3 пункта меню и курсор передвигается по ним кнопками. А как можно реализовать, чтобы когда курсор стоит на пункте меню, тот менял свой цвет и цвет фона? когда курсор переходит на другой, то первый обратно становится белым, а уже следующий цветной...

```
CONSOLE_CURSOR_INFO cci;
cci.bVisible = true;
cci.dwSize = 100;
SetConsoleCursorInfo(h, &cci);

COORD point;
point.X = 30;
point.Y = 15;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, point);
cout << "New Game" << endl;
point.X = 30;
point.Y = 20;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, point);
cout << "Help" << endl;
point.X = 30;
point.Y = 25;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, point);
cout << "Exit" << endl;
point.X = 30;
point.Y = 15;
SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, point);

while (1)
{
    int move = _getch();
    switch (move)
    {
    case 72:
    if (point.Y > 15)
        point.Y -= 5;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, point);
    break;
    case 80:

        if(point.Y<25)
            point.Y+=5;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, point);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция `SetConsoleTextAttribute()` позволяет задавать цвет текста и цвет фона. Соответственно, вам нужна постоянная перерисовка меню с меняющимися цветами фона и текста.